# Accessing Office 365 calendar using C# through EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to an Office 365 mailbox to get the calender information through C#.

I am getting the following error: `The Autodiscover service couldn't be located`.

My Code :

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, domain);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailid, RedirectionCallback);
CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

The RedirectionCallback Function

```
static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
{
    // Return true if the URL is an HTTPS URL.
    return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the URL manually to see if it connects?

Comment: Nope as i am not aware of the URL .. Any idea on how to get it